# How can I speed up my unit tests using cloud computing?

Tags: unit-testing, amazon-web-services, junit, cloud

I work on a project with a lot of legacy code that has some tests (in JUnit). Those unit tests are pretty slow and running them often slows me down. I plan on refactoring and optimizing them (so they're real unit tests), but before I do this, I'd like to speed them up just for now, by running them in parallel. Of course I could get myself some cluster and run them there, but that's not worth the hassle and the money. Is it possible to do so with some cloud services like e.g. Amazon AWS? Can you recommend me some articles where I could read more about it?

Answer (score 0):

Running unit tests in parallel requires 2 things:

1. Creating groups of multiple tests using either suites or JUnit categories
2. A way to launch each group of tests

Once you have #1, an easy way to get #2 is to use Continuous Integration.

*Do you already use Continuous Integration ?*

If not, it is easy to add.  One of the more popular ones is [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins)
Jenkins also supports [distributed builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) where a master code launches build jobs on slave nodes.  You could use this to run each of your groups in parallel.

*Continuous Integration in the Cloud*

Once you have Continuous Integration set up, you can move it into the cloud if you wish.

If you want to stick with jenkins, you can use

- [Cloud Bees](http://www.cloudbees.com/products/dev) which costs money
- Red Hat Openshift "Gears" [can be used to run Jenkins](https://blog.openshift.com/jenkins-in-the-cloud-enabling-continuous-integration-on-a-paas/).  I think it is possible to use gears in Amazon WS but I've never done it. You can run a few gears with limited memory usage for free, but if you need more it will cost money.

If you don't want to use Jenkins, there are other cloud based CIs including
[Travis-CI](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/getting-started/) which integrates with github.  Here is an [article about how to speed up builds in Travis](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/speeding-up-the-build/)